How to automatically refresh NON MATERIALIZED views in postgres?
How do you automatically refresh a view in postgres?
I want to add a script which automatically refreshes all views after a database migration.
How could I achieve this?
I know REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW exists, but what if you just want to refresh the definition of a normal view?

As for why I want this, well I have a view like
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MyView
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE...

Now I add another column to MyTable in a new migration, but the view will not contain the new column since it was defined before the new migration.
So I wanted to add a deployment step where all the views definitions are refreshed on any new migration.
What can you recommend?

You have to drop the view and create a new one. A view is a hardcoded query. MATERIALIZED has nothing to do with this, a MATERIALIZED VIEW will have the same issue.

You don't, a normal view will run it's query every time you use it per CREATE VIEW: CREATE VIEW defines a view of a query. The view is not physically materialized. Instead, the query is run every time the view is referenced in a query..  Read rest of document link for how to deal with changes.

Right, but then how do you deal with migrations? You have 10 views defined in 10 different migrations file, you add a new column to a table, now you have to add another migration refreshing the definition of all 10 views? That seems horrible DevX. What am I missing?

Why should a view be updated when you create a new column? The only one who knows, is you. Not the database. From the database perspective there is no reason to make any change to these views.

If I just want to make a view to filter a few rows, I want all the columns to always be present. I do
SELECT *
FROM X
WHERE (complicated filter)
I want this view to always contain the latest columns.

The way to deal like that is to drop and re-create all the affected views during the migration.  Or even simpler: just drop and re-create all your views during a schema version change.  That is simple, since you keep all your view definitions under version control.
An explanation why that is necessary: PostgreSQL doesn't store views as an SQL statement string, but it parses the query and stores the binary parse tree. Parsing resolves the * to all the column names at the time of the view creation, so if you add another column later, it won't have an effect on the view creation.
Since you complain about the bad developer experience: the benefit of that procedure is that PostgreSQL tracks dependencies between the view and its dependent objects and keeps you from dropping them or modifying them in a way that affects the view. This way, a view can never break and suddenly cause an error, just because one of its prerequisites is missing.

Thank you for your answer! Is there a convenience script or something like that that would allow one to drop and recreate all views from SQL files, that one can run as part of the CD pipeline? (Instead of having to do it manually)

You can just take the script from your version control system. If you don't have that yet, create it now and reuse it.
